# Property 'do' does not exist on type 'AngularFireList<unknown>'

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

So I hava a Angular 8 application and want to use the do operator from rxjs.

But I get an error on this line

So I googled. And I found a suggestion that I have to add this:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
```

But that doesnt work.

So I have this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { Course } from 'app/shared/model/course';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import { tap, filter, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()

export class CoursesService {

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  findAllCourses(): Observable<Course[]> {
    return this.db.list('courses').do(console.log);
  }
}
```

But I still get this error:

```
Property 'do' does not exist on type 'AngularFireList<unknown>'.ts(2339)
```

That the error will go away

Comment: You're trying to use the obsolete RxJS 5.x or before API. The old do() operator is named tap() (you're importing it, BTW), and it's used, as all operators since RxJS 6, using `obs.pipe(tap(...));` The Angular documentation about RxJS, and The RxJS documentation itself, are your friends. Don't red random old posts on the internet. Read the documentation.

Comment: You also need to read the AngularFire documentation: you must call valueChanges() or snapshotChanges() to have an Observable. https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the **[pipe()](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/186)** for chaining like:

```
.pipe(tap(data => console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data))))
```

Your code should be something like,

```
 return this.db.list('courses').snapshotChanges().pipe(
      tap(console.log),
```

Comment: Thank you. But I have this:  return this.db.list('courses').(console.log);

Comment: Thank you!! very nice. Without , at the end I assume :)